# Migrating coldfusion application to Lucee

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, lucee

Our server is changing from Coldfusion to a Lucee server and I'm tasked with updating our code for a couple of web applications. I'm not a guru of Coldfusion but I can often figure my way around things, to that end my query.

The code I'm converting over is throwing this error:
**Can't cast Object type [DateTime] to a value of type [Array]**

I have been working through all of the queries and making sure that the output is appropriately CAST which has resolved the majority of issues but the small block of code that is stumping me throws the above error. The code is:

```
<cfset summaryStartDate = ArrayMin( qSummaryData["minHours"] ) />
<cfset summaryMaxDate = ArrayMax( qSummaryData["maxHours"] ) />
<cfset summaryEndDate = DateAdd("d", -(DayofWeek(#summaryMaxDate#))+6, #summaryMaxDate# ) />
```

minHours and maxHours are both DATETIME format. I know in the coldfusion version they output like so:

summaryStartDate: 41204
summaryMaxDate: 43465
summaryEndDate: {ts '2019-01-04 00:00:00'}

Which, to me, means Coldfusion is doing a conversion in some way and Lucee doesn't do those (or at least from what I've read). The database is mySQL and the minHours and maxHours output as dates with 00:00:00 on the hours, for reference.

I'm probably missing something obvious but I can't see it.

Comment: What line is the error coming from, the first one?

Comment: @andrewdixon Good question.

The output I get says line 449 with this as the codePrintPlain output:

codePrintPlain": "447: \t\t\t\n448: \t\t\t\t\t\t\n449: \t\t<cfset summaryStartDate = ArrayMin( qSummaryData[\"minHours\"] ) />\n450: \t\t<cfset summaryMaxDate = ArrayMax( qSummaryData[\"maxHours\"] ) />\t\t\n451: \t\t<cfset summaryEndDate = DateAdd(\"d\", -(DayofWeek(#summaryMaxDate#))+6, #summaryMaxDate# ) />\n

Comment: @andrewdixon I've commented out each one to see if it was only one but the first two are definitely throwing that same error while the third throws up the error that the first two don't exist.

Comment: So the value being passed in `qSummaryData["minHours"]` is not an array, hence the `ArrayMin` erroring. If you cfdump the value of `qSummaryData["minHours"]` is it just a date?

Comment: I believe you also said `qSummaryData` is a query result set, if so, `qSummaryData["minHours"] ` is never going to be an array, it is just going to be the first value in the result set for the column `minHours` in the result set. I guess maybe in ACF it is an array of all the values for that column, but in Lucee it is just the first value in the result set of the query.

Comment: you could uses the query.reduce function (http://docs.lucee.org/reference/objects/query/reduce.html) to loop over the query rows and return the minimum value for the column.

Comment: There is an example here http://docs.lucee.org/reference/functions/queryreduce.html that doesn't something similar.

Comment: @andrewdixon Hi Andrew. Correct qSummaryData is the query that happens right before these cfsets, so you're correct it is the column output. From what I gather of the code sequence, the purpose of ArrayMin is to select the earliest date in that set and ArrayMax I presume would be the most recent date and coldfusion is doing the leg work to make it work as an array. I'll try and rewrite those so I'm avoiding the array transfer entirely and hope that resolves it.

Comment: Depending on how the query is used, you could also do the MIN/MAX in the SQL instead of CF...

Comment: @andrewdixon In ACF you can access a query like an array of rows nested in a structure keyed by column. Strange that's not listed in Lucee's [Language and Syntax Differences](http://docs.lucee.org/guides/developing-with-lucee-server/language-syntax-differences.html)

Comment: @Rain - Maybe it's not listed as a supported feature in the Adobe docs? I know of at least 1 function that doesn't treat query columns as an array. Was never sure if it working with ArrayMin/Mix was a happy side effect or documented behavior.

Comment: Code review time: `#summaryMaxDate#` doesn't need the `#`s.

Comment: @Rain Feel free to submit an update to that page on the Lucee docs, just click the pencil icon on the page to edit :-)

Answer (score 0):

I preface this answer with "it is not the greatest fix" but it does work. Taking my queue from andrewdixon I looked at side stepping the use of an array (which the data wasn't suited for) and looked at alternatives.

I settled on a query of queries, extracting the min value and then setting that in a cfset. Doing the same for max value following that. My two queries were:

```
<cfquery name="smallestFigure" dbtype="query">SELECT CAST(MIN(minHours) AS DATETIME) as outputMin FROM qSummaryData;</cfquery>
<cfquery name="largestFigure" dbtype="query">SELECT CAST(MAX(maxHours) AS DATETIME) as outputMax FROM qSummaryData;</cfquery>
```

I cfset these into summaryStartDate and summaryMaxDate so that this line (mentioned in the original post) could run:

```
<cfset summaryEndDate = DateAdd("d", -(DayofWeek(#summaryMaxDate#))+6, #summaryMaxDate# ) />
```

Shawn mentioned I didn't need the #'s around summaryMaxDate but I haven't made that change as yet. andrewdixon mentioned using query.reduce() as an alternative and I imagine that would be far more succinct than what I've done so if someone comes up with a better solution, please post as an answer.

Also thank you all for the support and ideas.

Comment: How are the min/max date used overall? Can it be done in the original query, or code (without a QoQ)? Just wondering if there are other alternatives...